# Is there a way to know if a Java program was started from the command line or from a jar file?

Tags: java, validation, command-line, double-click

I want to either display a message in the console or a pop up, so in case a parameter is not specified, I want to know to which should I display

Something like:

```
if( !file.exists() ) {
    if( fromCommandLine()){
        System.out.println("File doesn't exists");
    }else if ( fromDoubleClickOnJar() ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessage(null, "File doesn't exists");
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you start it from the command line does the application run without a GUI?

Comment: Interesting question (+1), but very tricky. Sorry for the deleted answer, I realized that this isn't reliable. I will do some tests.

Comment: @Jon It runs with a GUI in both cases.

Comment: @BalusC indeed. The fact you can run the jar from the cmd line makes it worst, but I think there must be a way to know where the class was loaded from, but I don't remember how it was.

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469047/can-i-find-out-if-the-java-program-was-launched-using-java-or-javaw

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The straight forward answer is that you cannot tell how the JVM was launched.

But for the example use-case in your question, you don't really need to know how the JVM was launched.  What you *really* need to know is whether the user will see a message written to the console.  And the way to do that would be something like this:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console != null) {
        console.format("File doesn't exists%n");
    } else if (!GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessage(null, "File doesn't exists");
    } else {
        // Put it in the log
    }
 }
```

The javadoc for [Console](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html), while not water tight, strongly hints that a Console object (if it exists) writes to a console and cannot be redirected.

Thanks @Stephen Denne for the `!GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` tip.

Comment: `GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` only checks a property (useful as a kind of "please don't try" setting). You'd also want to catch `HeadlessException` in case the property wasn't set, but there is no display (or keyboard or mouse) available.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not clear on the question but I'm going to interpret it as you want to differentiate between the following 2

java -jar fred.jar

and

java package.Main

Here is an outline line of the program

```
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.*;
...
HostIdentifier hostId = new HostIdentifier("localhost");
MonitoredHost monitoredHost = MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost(hostId);
Set jvms = monitoredHost.activeVms();
for (Object i: jvms) {
   VmIdentifier id = new VmIdentifier("//" + i + "?mode=r");
   MonitoredVm vm = monitoredHost.getMonitoredVm(id, 0);   
   System.out.println(i);
   System.out.println("\t main class: " + MonitoredVmUtil.mainClass(vm, false));
   System.out.println("\t main args: " + MonitoredVmUtil.mainArgs(vm));
   System.out.println("\t jvmArgs: " + MonitoredVmUtil.jvmArgs(vm));
   monitoredHost.detach(vm);
}
```

The call `MonitoredVmUtil.mainClass(vm, false)` will either return '`jar`' or the name of your main class eg `Main`.

You have to use `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar` to compile and run.

Answer (score 3):

The  `System.console()` trick seems to do the work.

Here's an alternative: there's a method in the class `Class` [getProtectionDomain()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain()) which may be used to know the  source of the code the the location from there.

The funny is, this method is available since 1.2

I knew I used this before, here's the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file/1429275#1429275) by  [erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474/erickson)

Here's the proof of concept:

```
public class FromJar {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        if ( FromJar.class
                 .getProtectionDomain()
                 .getCodeSource()
                 .getLocation()
                 .getFile()
                 .endsWith(".jar") ) {

            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Launched from Jar" );

       } else {
            System.out.println("Launched NOT from Jar :P ");
       }
    }
}
```

Here's a short ( 1m aprox ) video to see this code running ( and being written with [cat](https://xkcd.com/378/) :-o )

[image: Youtube video]

Comment: What would you want to show for `java -cp fromjar.jar FromJar`

Comment: Eh, your question was thus: "How to differentiate if the class was launched as Java Application (as standalone class without `-jar` argument) or as JAR file? (with `-jar` argument)" ? Your initial question namely didn't imply that. I understood that it were JAR files in both cases. Else checking would indeed be very easy...

Comment: @BalusC, yeap, actually what I need is to know if the user doubleclicked on a jar or if it started from the console.  I think the `System.console()` answer is the correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
if (System.console() != null) {
    // Console attached to the JVM: command prompt output
    System.out.println("...");
} else {
    // No console: use Swing
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect.  System.console() can return a non-null value, but System.out may still be redirected.  (In fact, I can think of two scenarios ...)

Answer (score 0):

From http://java.itags.org/java-essentials/15972/

```
try {
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
} catch(Throwable ex) {
    System.out.println("No graphical environment is available.");
}
```

Comment: Nice one, tested it, but this never throws. I think this is more useful to test if there's any graphics device (headless or not).

Comment: If I open my console an run a java program, the graphics environment will be there still.

Answer (score 0):

it's true that it is impossible to tell how the JVM was invoked.
but... there's a way to side step this.
you assumed that when the user double clicked on a JAR, then there's GUI running...
ok. so let's extend this assumption.
check.. from where the class was invoked, the directory.
check that directory..
assuming it's a normal usage, when there's a *.jar file, then the user must've started the app from a jar..
but one flaw is that the user can also click on the main class file.
hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the input arguments with RuntimeMBean.getInputArguments(), this can be used to detect when debugging is enabled.

EDIT: However, the -jar argument isn't one of them. :(