# Determine is application has been started via Java or Javaw?

Tags: java, console, javaw

I have a GUI program that is executed by default via `javaw.exe` using a startup wrapper created with Launch4j.

This program can also be executed from command-line and then print output to the console.

How can I detect if a console is visible, hence that the text I output via `System.out.println()` is visible?

From my understanding this depends on whether the program has been started via Javaw/wrapper or directly by `java -jar myprog.jar`. Is there a way to distinguish both starts methods from withing the program?

Comment: Why do you want to detect the way application is run ? It may by that the way application is run is not issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `System.console()` returns `null`, there's no console, which happens when you start the program with `javaw` instead of `java`. Example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.console() != null) {
            System.out.println("Hello on the console");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, there's no console");
        }
    }
}
```

Try compiling this and then starting it with either `java Example` or `javaw Example`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469047/can-i-find-out-if-the-java-program-was-launched-using-java-or-javaw

Comment: however some IDEs also run with javaw and get the stdin and stdout directly

Answer (score -1):

$0 is the program that started the last cmd -- in the shell.