# Get name of executable jar from within main() method

Tags: java, program-entry-point, apache-commons-cli

I've created an executable jar and using commons-cli to give the user the ability to specify command line parameters when he launches the client.  Everything works fine.  However, when I print the usage statement for the jar, I would like to show the following:

```
usage: java -jar myprog.jar <options> <file>
--help Display the help message
--debug Enable debugging
....
```

Printing of all the options is easily done with commons-cli.  However, the "usage" line is the head scratcher.  I cannot seem to figure out a way to get the "myprog.jar" name from the args[] that are passed to the application.

Is there any easy way of doing this?  I could use a pretty convoluted method to back trace from my class' classloader and figure out if it is contained within a jar, but that seems like a fairly ugly answer to what should be a pretty simple question.

```
private String getPath(Class cls) {
    String cn = cls.getName();
    String rn = cn.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    String path =
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rn).getPath();
    int ix = path.indexOf("!");
    if(ix >= 0) {
        return path.substring(0, ix);
    } else {
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file?lq=1 ?

Comment: I did see that link already, but it looked as though it was almost a "hack" as well.  I cannot believe that there is not a more direct solution.  Additionally, the API states that "getCodeSource()" may return null, but does not elaborate under which conditions, so I naturally wondered if this was a "fail-safe" method to use.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here you go:

```
new java.io.File(SomeClassInYourJar.class.getProtectionDomain()
  .getCodeSource()
  .getLocation()
  .getPath())
.getName()
```

**Edit:** I saw your comment about getSourceCode API. Well, this is probably the best you can do in Java. About `getCodeSource()` returning `null`, I think it mainly happens on classes in `java.lang.*` and other special classes for which the source location is "hidden". Should work for your own classes though.

Comment: Thanks - that's the same thing that @Charles pointed to in the SO link.  My biggest concern as I mentioned above is that the api for `getCodeSource()` indicates that it can be null, but does not elaborate under which conditions.

Comment: The other problem with this is that it does not take into account the fact that the class file may be nested within archives.  So I would still need to check for a `!` substring.  Like I said, it seems a little clunky and am quite surprised that Java does not have a better solution.

Comment: It's mostly because there is rarely a reason to know the name of the jar file you're running from. The functionality should (ideally) be independent of the name.

Comment: @rodion for me the above is giving classes! as output

Comment: Any idea if this technique will translate to GraalVM AOTC? I'd like to create a multicall binary.

Answer (score 2):

You should in any case add a .toURI() before you call getPath(). Thats because of some quirks in java's URL implementation - see [how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java) for details.