# How to I get the name of a program in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program and want to be able to get the name of program (meaning the .jar program that is opened to start the application). I have searched around and have been unable to find a method that works for my use case. Anyone have a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Check this also :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158235/get-name-of-executable-jar-from-within-main-method