# Using an image in a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I can't seem to get this right...

I have a Java project in Eclipse called MyProject. In its root is the folders bin, src, and resources. Inside of resources, I have an image named `myImage.gif`.

In my code, I want to use this image, and I want it to work whether or not this is running from a Jar file. I currently am doing this

```
ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/myImage.gif"));
```

but it is spitting out a null when I run it through Eclipse (not as a Jar).

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: "/resources/myImage.gif" is an absolute path try "resources/myImage.gif"

Comment: same problem unfortunately

Comment: print the current path and extend it by 'resources/myImage.gif'  Check if this is the path to your image.

Comment: InputStream stream = yourClass.class.getResourceAsStream('/resources/myImage.gif');`

Comment: yes it is the path to the image.

Comment: Stupid idea.  Crack open the Jar and make sure the image has been included

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482560/can-you-tell-on-runtime-if-youre-running-java-from-within-a-jar

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not running from Jar, this is just from running in eclipse. Please read the question, thanks.

Comment: @CodeGuy I thought *"Using an image in a JAR file"*  was pretty obvious actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to tell Eclipse to treat `resources` as a source folder then you should be able to say

```
ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/myImage.gif"));
```

When you come to build the JAR you'll have to ensure that the contents of the `resources` directory go into the top level of the JAR file in order for the same path to work in the JAR case, i.e.

```
META-INF
  MANIFEST.MF
com
  example
    MyClass.class
myImage.gif
```

Alternatively, and probably the more common Java idiom, put the image file in the same directory as the `.java` file (`src/com/example` in this case) and then use `getResource` without the leading slash

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myImage.gif"));
```

`Class.getResource` resolves a relative path like that against the package of the class in question.  Again, you need to have the same structure in the JAR when you come to build that, this time with `myImage.gif` under `com/example`.

Answer (score 0):

**Place resources into src** and Eclipse will copy it into bin.

```
ImageIcon ii =
   new ImageIcon(
      ImageIO.read(
         getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            "resources/myImage.gif" )));
```

Without / before the path.

Comment: Nope, same thing....how do I have eclipse refresh the whole thing so that it cleans and builds so that resources will be in bin?

Comment: And even if I manually put it in the bin, this still does not work unfortunately. Same problem, NullPointer...

Comment: No, this does not work. I am running FROM ECLIPSE not from a Jar file.  I need a solution that works for JAR and FROM ECLIPSE.

Comment: I test it from Eclipse NOW!

Comment: @CodeGuy as per [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843166/592139) the correct path depends on exactly where you've put the files.  Using `classLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/myImage.gif")` would work if you put the file at `src/resources/myImage.gif`, etc. - if `myImage.gif` is directly inside `src` then you just need `"myImage.gif"` without the `resources/`